# Kendo Batch Update without Incell editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, batch-updates

I'm trying to do an ajax batch update without enabling InCell Editing in a Kendo Grid. I want to allow the users to select a bunch of rows, and then mark them as a certain status (selected from a drop down) and then do a batch update. Is there a way I can pass the currently selected grid items in a custom toolbar action? Something like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Grid>().Name("Grid")
      .DataSource(ds => ds
          .Ajax()
...
      )
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Custom().Action("Grid_Update", "Sessions", new {sessionId = ViewBag.SessionID, cycles = **selectedGridItems**}))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you asked cannot be achieved that simply.

Instead I would like to point you that you can still use [batch](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-batch) updates even without incell editing mode. For example the code library used **[here](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/external-editing-container-for-batch-editable-grid)** does not use InCell editing but still have the "Save changes" button and it still sends the modified records to the server the same way.